# Linear Regression Residuals - Should I "standardise" the results and how to do this

Tags: python, scipy, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am a biologist. I want to copy an approach that I read in a paper: "To permit associations with death rates to be investigated independently from weight, residuals for death rates were calculated by subtracting the predicted from observed values".

I have a set of death rates (that range from about 0.1 to 0.5), a set of body weights (that range from about 2 to 80), and I want to calculate residuals for the death rates after accounting for body weight.

I wrote this code:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import sys


# This reads in the weight and mortality data to two lists. 
Weight = []
Mortality = []
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
        line = line.strip().split()
        Weight.append(float(line[-2]))
        Mortality.append(float(line[-1]))

# This calculates the regression equation.
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(Mortality,Weight)

# This calculates the predicted value for each observed value
obs_values = Mortality
pred_values = []
for i in obs_values:
    pred_i = float(i) * float(slope) + float(intercept)
    pred_values.append(pred_i)

# This prints the residual for each pair of observations
for obs_v,pred_v in zip(obs_values,pred_values):
    Residual = str(obs_v - pred_v)
    print Residual
```

My question is, when I run this code, some of my residuals seem quite large:

> ```
> > Sample1 839.710240214 
> > Sample2 325.787250084 
> > Sample3 -41.3006000084
> > Sample4 -70.6676280159
> > Sample5 267.05319407
> > Sample6 399.204820103
> > Sample7 560.723474144
> > Sample8 766.292670196
> > Sample9 267.05319407
> > Sample10 2.7499420027
> ```

I'm wondering, do these results seem "normal"/ should they be "standardised" in some way/ did I do something wrong to obtain residuals for mortality rates after accounting for weight?

I would appreciate simple "plain english" answers with possibly code snippets if it were possible, as I am not a statistics expert!

Many thanks

Comment: first we need to find the correct formula for what you want to achive. then we can correct your code

Comment: Residuals should sum to 0, your numbers don't seem to do so. On the other hand, your given output seems disconnected from the code, since nothing in your code prints the word "Sample"

Comment: In your model `Mortality` is the independent and `Weight` is the dependent variable. I think it should be the other way around if you don't claim that a person's mortality prob/likelihood affects their weight.

Comment: Thank you. @JohnColeman the tip about residuals should add to 0 is great, thanks; using the code below, I added in the word "sample" manually, just to explain what my answer was; I can see now that this may be confusing, won't do it again; will just print the exact output. Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into the documentation of [`scipy.stats.linregess()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html): The first argument is `x`, the abscissa, and the second is `y`, your observed value. So if `obs_values = Mortality` should be the observed values you have to permute the two arguments of linear regression and have to calculate the predicted values based on the `Weight` as `x` (not `Mortality` as `y`):

```
# This calculates the regression equation.
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x=Weight, y=Mortality)

# This calculates the predicted value for each observed value
obs_values = Mortality
pred_values = []
for i in Weight:
    pred_i = float(i) * float(slope) + float(intercept)
    pred_values.append(pred_i)
```

Additional you can reduce (and speed up) your code drastically by using numpy (scipy uses it anyway).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import sys

# This reads in the weight and mortality data to two arrays.
arr = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])
Weight = arr[:,-2]
Mortality = arr[:,-1]

# This calculates the regression equation.
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x=Weight,y=Mortality)

# This calculates the predicted value for each observed value
obs_values = Mortality
pred_values = slope * Weight + intercept

# This prints the residual for each pair of observations
Residual = obs_values - pred_values
print(Residuals)
```

Comment: I think you should change the for loop as well. `pred_i = float(i) * float(slope) + float(intercept)` would still be wrong as `i` is iterated over `Mortality` but not `Weight`.

Comment: Yes, I saw it after answering, too. I edited it yet.

Comment: Thank you, now the residuals add up to 0 and the numbers don't seem as unrealistically high. I will definitely look into numpy more; I can see how it would have been useful here.

Comment: Can I just ask, I've just that the standardisation would involve the residual - mean / SE. I understand that I've now calculated the residuals, I don't think I've standardised them. I understand this would mean, for each residual; subtract the mean and divide by the standard error. I can see the std_err; I'm not sure which mean I am meant to use, I assume the mean of the obs_values list? So just, for each residual, subtract the mean of the obs_values list and divide by the standard error?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm not meant to ask a follow up question here, if anyone could tell me how I can continue a discussion of my original question (with code and without a character count) without clicking "answer question", I will gladly move this text to that section; I apologise.

My last question was how "To permit associations with death rates to be investigated independently from weight". My next question is just out of curiosity, if were to expand on this, say if I wanted to examine death rates, independently from weight and height?

I've written this code, for my data these residuals do add up to 0, but I just wanted to check with the experts that this is the way that I would go about this for future reference:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import sys

dat = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1],dtype={"names":("SpeciesName","Mortality","Height","Weight"),"formats":("S40","f4","f4","f4")})
mymodel = smf.ols("Mortality~Height+Weight",data=dat).fit()
Residues = list(mymodel.resid_pearson)
SpeciesList = list(dat["SpeciesName"])
for species,residue in zip(SpeciesList,Residues):
    print species + "\t" + str(residue)
```

Once again, apologies if I have written this in the wrong section; I didn't feel that it was a new question, and as a comment I couldn't add code; I will gladly make this a new question if that is more appropriate.